# cannot access superclass from class

Tags: java, jaxb, illegalaccessexception

I have created a simple java client that builds XML message based on classes generated from XSD and then sens it to the web service.
It works fine when I test it from my workstation but when I load classes to Oracle database I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "Root Thread" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: cannot access superclass from class
at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newInstance(Proxy.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.annotationForMap(AnnotationParser.java)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getAllFieldAnnotations(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getAllFieldAnnotations(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findFieldProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java)
```

I thought that it might be caused by classes being in different packages so then I moved all the classes to the single default package but it didn't help.
I also replaced all protected/private fields/classes with public, still the same issue.

This is the line where I think it fails:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PurchaseOrder.class);
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

PurchaseOrder class:

```
<code>
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PurchaseOrder", propOrder = {
    "purchaseOptions"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "PurchaseOrder")
public class PurchaseOrder {

    @XmlElement(name = "PurchaseOptions")
    public ArrayOfPurchaseOptionDescription purchaseOptions;

    public ArrayOfPurchaseOptionDescription getPurchaseOptions() {
        return purchaseOptions;
    }

    public void setPurchaseOptions(ArrayOfPurchaseOptionDescription value) {
        this.purchaseOptions = value;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ArrayOfPurchaseOptionDescription", propOrder = {
    "purchaseOptionDescription"
})
public class ArrayOfPurchaseOptionDescription {

    @XmlElement(name = "PurchaseOptionDescription", nillable = true)
    public List<PurchaseOptionDescription> purchaseOptionDescription;

    public List<PurchaseOptionDescription> getPurchaseOptionDescription() {
        if (purchaseOptionDescription == null) {
            purchaseOptionDescription = new ArrayList<PurchaseOptionDescription>();
        }
        return this.purchaseOptionDescription;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code of the class `PurchaseOrder.class`.

Comment: I updated my post with PurchaseOrder class

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud remove the XML type name like :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "purchaseOptions"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "PurchaseOrder")
public class PurchaseOrder {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mickael. PurchaseOrder class references other class like ArrayOfPurchaseOptionDescription (added in my post), which then references PurchaseOptionDescription class. There are many other classes referenced. All of them have XMLType annotation with name=class name. Do you think I should remove XMLType name annotation in all classes? Not sure how the XMLType name attribute is related to the error message I get.